# Group by month and year across multiple years

Tags: mysql, group-by, union

Looking for help with what I'm sure is a simple rookie mistake. The GROUP BY function in my query is not distinguishing between different years. Data for July for all years are being included on the same row rather than by month+year. What am I missing?

This is the query that other than the GROUP BY function works properly:

```
SELECT  
`index`,  
`month`,  
`year`,   
sum(maintained) as maintained,   
sum(repaired) as repaired  
FROM
(  
SELECT   
        MONTH(`service_date`) AS 'index',  
        MONTHNAME(`service_date`) AS 'month',  
        YEAR(`service_date`) AS 'year',  
        COUNT(`service_date`) AS 'maintained',  
        0  AS repaired  
FROM  `service_log`  
GROUP BY MONTH(`service_date`)   

UNION  

SELECT   
        MONTH(`service_date`) AS 'index',  
        MONTHNAME(`service_date`) AS 'month',  
        YEAR(`service_date`) AS 'year',  
        0 AS 'maintained',  
        COUNT(`other_repairs`) AS 'repaired'  
FROM  `service_log`  
GROUP BY MONTH(`service_date`)  
)  
  
AS union_name  
GROUP BY `year`,`month`  
ORDER BY `year` DESC,`index`  DESC
```

The output is in this form:

| Month | Maint | Repair |
| --- | --- | --- |
| July 2022 | 80 | 45 |
| June 2022 | 30 | 21 |
| May 2022 | 20 | 26 |
| April 2022 | 30 | 19 |

Comment: Your query is not correct, it uses incomplete grouping. Your `year` column obtains indefinite value. Enable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` then edit your query until it works without errors. PS. I think that the logic needed and the logic realized in the query are not the same.

Comment: Can you share your input data and the description of what your code should do?

Comment: @Lemon, the input data are contained in a single MySQL table including a column "service_date" in date format. What the code should do is illustrated above in the output table with 3 columns summing table rows grouped by both month and year.  (In the query reference posted above, for simplicity I've removed the WHERE clauses that define the two joined SELECT clauses.)

Comment: PROBLEM RESOLVED.  I merely needed to add  YEAR(`service_date`)  to each of the GROUP functions within the union and it works as expected.  GROUP BY MONTH(`service_date`), YEAR(`service_date`)   
Thanks for the answers

Comment: If your output is now correct, it is just by chance, as you still don't have an `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` condition as pointed by Akina.